# What does "churir" mean?

Tags: traducción, méxico, significado

I was watching a Mexican video once, and I heard it.

A co-worker of mine claims to know it's meaning, translating it to "dent", but I'm not quite sure, and I can't find any reference online.

The original context was:

> Me dejaste la mano toda churida, peor de lo que estaba.

I can't quite post the original video since it's been removed from Youtube, but I remember the person who said it had his hand hurt and was being examined, but it seemed as if the doctor left it worse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means `to wrinkle`.  The word applies mainly to skin (fruit skin, human skin, etcetera).. it could also be applied to clothing if you think of it as.. `fabric skin`

*Land can also be `churido`, but land can also be referred to as the earth's skin.*

Various synonyms:

- Withered
- Dilapidated
- Aged (visually and physically)
- Deflated
- Sunken in
- Dented (as you already mentioned)

> Me dejaste la mano toda churida, peor de lo que estaba.

---

> You left my hand completely wrinkled, worse than it was already.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what's the source of the information?

Comment: I googled for the word `churido` and the preview for this page appeared.  http://bit.ly/1icN6nv.  Also, under the first result I saw `envejecido` and made an immediate relegation and assumption.

Comment: http://www.wordmeaning.org/other-meanings.asp?ID=36545, http://espadiamapas.webs.com/mexicanslangtoenglish.html

Comment: If "churros" is the word for a certain pastry, does it refer to a "wrinkled" pastry? Or are the two words, churro and churir unrelated?

Comment: You know, I had the exact same thoughts when looking this up.  A churro does have a wrinkled (or ridged) texture and I suppose that texture is what I am referring to.  `Ridged texture`.  Unfortunately, I cannot find anything else on the  word `churir`..

Comment: that is in fact, a northern regionalism. I bet your friend lives either on the border towns of Tijuana or Mexicali. The term comes from the wrongful transliteration of an english word (spanglish) in thi scase, "*crushing*"  as in "*crushing sundays paper into a ball*". Other words used in the north with a similar origin in spanglish: **Parkear** (*Estacionarse*, *to Park a car*, also **Parkeadero** or *Parking spot*.) **Apuchar** (to *Push*, *empujar*) **Brekas** (*Brakes, Frenos*). an amusing example: "**Apuchale** bien a las **Brekas** para **Parkear** el Carro" makes perfect sense

Comment: @hlecuanda - Great info.  Could you put it in an answer?

Comment: @aparente001 I'll ask in meta to allow these creole forms, Here, in the northern border there is a  unique environment where spanishspeakers of very diverse origins share close spaces, and the language absorbs sorts of *Hispanicized* loan-words that are unique to the Mexico/US shared border .However, that sort of creolization **specially** with English is frowned upon by scholars and language enthusiasts sometimes considered "a sin against language" I hold no such prejudice any more, but being aware of the stigma associated with **Spanglish** I'd rather ask than risk having questions deleted.

Comment: @hlecuanda - I'll be very interested to learn more about these northern Mexico regionalisms.  Can you help me come up with a tag, once you feel you've gotten enough of a green light to proceed with confidence?