# Is the resemblance between the words "churir" and "churros" more than coincidence?

Tags: etimología

In a previous [question](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/5560/what-does-churir-mean), it was established that the word "churir" means "to wrinkle."

"Churros," refers to a certain "wrinkled" pastry. Given their resemblance, is the one word essentially a derivative of the other?

Comment: I too am very interested in this answer.  Surely, the `chur` in both words share a significant root.  The `ch` has a wide occurrence in itself, http://bit.ly/1prUUfb,  even Arabic uses this sound, so it's hard to conclude it being of latin or arabic origin.

Comment: According to RAE, the origin of the word *churro* is onomatopoeic (from the sound the dough makes when fried). It's similar to *chirriar*. *Churir* is not standard Spanish, so it may be harder to trace its origins.

Comment: @rsanchez, you should make this comment an answer, because it seems the right one (to me, at least)

Comment: what's churir? i'm Spanish and never heard that word!

Comment: @rupps: The previous question was "linked to" in the fourth word of my own question.

Comment: opps I write faster than I read :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The etymology of the word "churro" is an [onomatopoeia](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/churro) of the sound of frying dough, so no, it's not the least bit related to "churir."